# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi while installing cffi 1.11.5 package

Tags: python, linux, paramiko, system-administration

`enter code here`I'm trying to install paramiko module in my linux server. The pip is blocked on the server, So i am manually copying the package zips and installing them from setup.py

when i try installing paramiko i get

```
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pynacl>=1.0.1')
```

so i download the PyNaCl package, but i get

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.1.0')
```

pynacl needs cffi 1.1.0 above:
so while installing cffi1.11.5 i get the below error:

```
 [root@homecffi-1.11.5]# python3.5 setup.py install
        running install
---
---
        installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg

--
--
        building '_cffi_backend' extension
        gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/local/lib/libffi-3.1/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/c/_cffi_backend.o
        c/_cffi_backend.c: In function ‘b_callback’:
        c/_cffi_backend.c:5911: warning: ‘ffi_prep_closure’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/ffi.h:341)
        gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/c/_cffi_backend.o -L$(libdir)/../lib64 -lffi -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Debian or Ubuntu machine,

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

and then try again.

For other distributions, the installation method and package name may be different.

Comment: linux , red hat 5.

Comment: `yum install libffi-devel`, then, maybe. It's also possible that modern versions of libffi (and thus cffi) aren't compatible with such an old version of Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find XYZ` also appears when linking with `-static` and there is no `libXYZ.a`.  Development packages typically contain the .a versions, although some distros seem to think static libraries are antiquated enough to drop support completely.  You may have to build the library from source.